# Javascript - Display videoID using Youtube Data API

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Trying to work through a program I currently have, where I am unable to view the `videoID` from a search query.
I have the following code at the moment:

```
function makeRequest() {
    var q = $('#query').val();
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
    q: q,
    part: 'snippet',
    maxResults: 20
    });
}

request.execute(function(response) {
    $('#results').empty()
    var srchItems = response.result.items;
    $.each(srchItems, function(index, item){
        vidTitle = item.snippet.title;
        vidThumburl = item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
        vidThumbimg = '<pre><img id="thumb" src="' + vidThumburl + '" alt="No Image Available." style="width:102px;height:64px"></pre>';
        vidID = item.id.videoId;
        $('#results').append('<pre>' + vidTitle + vidThumbimg + vidID+ '</pre>');
        })
    })
```

Looking at the last two substantial lines, I thought that the code would be enough to display the `videoID` as plain text, however, that is not currently working.
Any advice on how to properly display the `videoID` would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of `response.result.items` and show the output for `'<pre>' + vidTitle + vidThumbimg + vidID+ '</pre>'` this will save me opening up the youtube API and should be able to answer this much quicker. Thank you. **Mainly the Json result** but maybe I could explain why your vidID isn't displaying.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863807/youtube-data-api-v3-using-javascript

Comment: is it me, or you looking at "item"? I thought it was supposed to be "items"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As additional information, try using the [sample code provided by Google](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript).

Here is the code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27070611/5995040) (made some adjustment):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="buttons">
    <label> <input id="query" value='cats' type="text"/><button id="search-button"   onclick="keyWordsearch()">Search</button></label>    
    <div id="container">
      <h1>Search Results</h1>
      <ul id="results"></ul>
    </div>           
    <script>
     function keyWordsearch(){
        gapi.client.setApiKey('API_KEY');
        gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
                makeRequest();
        });
}
    function makeRequest() {
        var q = $('#query').val();
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
                q: q,
                part: 'snippet', 
                maxResults: 10
        });
        request.execute(function(response)  {                                                                                    
                $('#results').empty()
                var srchItems = response.result.items;                
                $.each(srchItems, function(index, item) {
                vidTitle = item.snippet.title;  
                vidThumburl =  item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
                vidID = "video ID : " + item.id.videoId             
                vidThumbimg = '<pre><img id="thumb" src="'+vidThumburl+'" alt="No  Image Available." style="width:204px;height:128px"></pre>';                   

                $('#results').append('<pre>' + vidTitle + vidThumbimg + vidID +'</pre>');                      
        })  
    })  
}
  </script> 
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady">  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Funny enough, my code started working after posting this question. I am not 100% sure why, maybe I forgot to save a file or my server wasn't updating, but thank you for your response!